# Create a New Project React Native not working

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I'm having a problem when I try to create a new react native app, I'm getting the output below when I try to use `create-react-native-app`

> create-react-native-app : The term 'create-react-native-app' is not
>   recognized as the name of a complete, function, script file, or
>   operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
>   included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: make sure that you've installed the package `create-react-native-app` globally & you are passing your project name correctly; refer [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/03/13/introducing-create-react-native-app)

Comment: @TusharWalzade yes

Comment: `create-react-native-app` has been deprecated and is no longer supported you should be using [Expo](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/) instead.

Comment: As a rule, don't make any demands on users of this system to help you it's a community you ask a question and users will help. Questions containing 'as soon as possible give me answer this question' is not suitable for a community system the only reason I did not close was the fact that the subject of your question is relevant to a lot of people

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`create-react-native-app` is no more in use. 
After installing React Native in your system use `react-native init "YourAppName"`